# Worklight 6.2 : Unable to add multiple js files in windows phone 8 environment

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-8, ibm-mobilefirst

I created a multipage app using Worklight for Android,iOS & Windows Phone 8 platforms. In that app, I have to include multiple js files in some pages, which is creating issues in the Windows phone 8 environment.

Issue : If I include multiple js files, only first js file is loading in Windows phone 8 environment.

I created a sample application using Worklight multi-page app to demonstrate the issue.

In the Page1.html, I included 2 js files.

```
<script>
    $.getScript(path + "js/Page1.js");
    $.getScript(path + "js/Sample.js");
</script>

<p>
    Currently <b>Page1.html</b> page is loaded.
</p>

<input type="button" class="appButton" value="Show Alert" onclick="alertHello();" />
<input type="button" class="appButton" value="SimpleDialog from Page1" onclick="currentPage.buttonClick();" />
<input type="button" class="appButton" value="Insert Fragment" onclick="currentPage.insertFragment();" />

<div id="FragmentsDiv"></div>

<input type="button" class="appButton" value="BACK" onclick="currentPage.back();" />
```

Code in sample.js file

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("sample.js loaded");
});

function alertHello()
{
    alert("hello");
}
```

When i tried to run the app in Windows phone 8 environment, Only the Page1.js is loading.

STEPS TO REPRODUCE ERROR

1. Click "Load Page1.html"
2. Click "Show Alert"

I am not getting the alert "hello" when I tried in windows phone 8 emulator/device.

Any help in solving the issue will be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you look at the multi-page sample app provided by IBM Worklight that demonstrates how it should be done for Windows Phone 8? Take a good look at the code: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#GS_client_dev

Comment: Yes, I have used the multi-page sample app only. As from the doc, the path for windows phone 8 app is different and that value is included using "path" variable while loading the script. My issue is , the first js file is loading but the second one is not.

Comment: The sample is working, so if yours is not working - please provide a fully working Worklight project that can be debugged, otherwise the provided code blocks are not enough.

Comment: In the sample, only one js file is there. If we include one more, the second file is not loading.

Comment: What is the file structure of the project? Is the page located next to the index.html or inside a pages\ folder? If you load the second page from the pages\ folder (from which you loaded the first page), then the path is not the same path anymore, I think that for the second page you will need to add ".." to get back into the pages folder to find the second page.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9WNWkGc4q2Oc2NKTGFuaGlpS1U/edit?usp=sharing . Please check this link to get the fully working Worklight project.

Comment: Is something supposed to not work in this sample? Everything works.

Comment: Is the Sample.js file also loading for you in the Page1? Its not working in Windows phone 8 emulator/device.

Comment: Per my answer - everything is working in your sample when i test it in the WP8 emulator, that is why an actual reproduction if required. See Carlos's answer as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait for the first script to be done to load the second script.
getScript takes a second parameter you can pass a function, or you can use promises like and chain with a done() function

```
<script>
  $.getScript(path + "js/Page1.js").done(function(){
    $.getScript(path + "js/sample.js");
  });
</script>
```

I tried my self and it works[image]

also notice that in your question in your code use use Sample.js with upper case "S" and in your comments you mentioned sample.js with lower case "s". I use sample.js in both file name and code.

Comment: Thank you Carlos. However I am disappointed that there is such a limitation for Windows mobile dev, and we have to go with this workaround. Reusability has gone for a toss over here.

Answer (score 0):

Testing your sample project in windows Phone 8 emulator (via Visual Studio 12), after clicking the Page 1 button I got an alert saying "sample.js loaded". I then clicked on the Show Alert button and got an alert saying "hello".

Cannot reproduce...
Your sample as-is is working just fine in Worklight Studio 6.2.0.00-20140818-1919 (same version and build as yours).

Maybe you should edit your question and provide the full steps you have taken in order to reproduce this; maybe you are missing a step.

What I've done:

1. Imported the project
2. Right-clicked on the Windows Phone 8 folder > Run As > Visual Studio project
3. VS opens > click on the "play" button
4. WP8 emulator opens > did the above

Comment: Even I have seen this same issue. Just not able to figure out what's wrong, probably I am a bit biased. But apart from this issue of not loading, this change in style of importing javascript file is actually a headache for us. Because now, we have override all of the html pages with '$.script(..)' import only for windows. The '<script ..>' import should work for all, shouldn't it?